# Issue With Header and Footer Include

Tags: php, html, header, include, footer

I'm having an issue trying getting my fixed header and footer to show using a php include

Here is my HTML

```
<?php include '_includes/header.php' ?>

<div class="neo__wrapper">

    <div class="neo__container">

    </div>

</div>

<?php include '_includes/footer.php' ?>
```

My SASS (used for nesting)

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 0;
 border: none;
}

html,body{ 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.neo__wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;

.neo__container{
     width: 960px;
     height: 3000px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
}

header{
 background:#ccc;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100px; 
 top: 0;
}

footer{
 background:#ccc;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm just building a framework so my header.php is just

```
<header></header>
```

and my footer.php is

```
<footer></footer>
```

Basically, my page should just have a gray fixed header and footer

Comment: `<header><?php include '_includes/header.php' ?></header>` if `header.php` is all that CSS you've shown us. However, that CSS would need to be wrapped in `<style></style>` inside `<head></head>` or as a link to the stylesheet. Not sure what the question's about though.

Comment: Your `neo__wrapper` CSS is unclosed which breaks the CSS before it gets to the header/footer declarations. *EDIT* Nevermind, just noticed you were using SASS, are you sure its compiling correctly? It's working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that it was an issue regarding WAMP, so PHP wasn't even running in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Your including an empty file.

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyCSSFile.css"></head>
```

also, if you are doing a header and footer on every page, include this code into them as well. in `header.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyCSSFile.css">
</head>
<body>
```

and in `footer.php`

```
<footer>
<script src="MyJavascriptFile.js"></script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt that should be `<header></header>` but more like `<head></head>` - `<header>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header is a completely different tag.